# Android in app billing - usage of enums

Tags: android, enums, in-app-billing

In the example coding of in app billing it uses

```
public enum ResponseCode {
    RESULT_OK,
    RESULT_USER_CANCELED,
    RESULT_SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE,
    RESULT_BILLING_UNAVAILABLE,
    RESULT_ITEM_UNAVAILABLE,
    RESULT_DEVELOPER_ERROR,
    RESULT_ERROR;

    // Converts from an ordinal value to the ResponseCode
    public static ResponseCode valueOf(int index) {
        ResponseCode[] values = ResponseCode.values();
        if (index < 0 || index >= values.length) {
            return RESULT_ERROR;
        }
        return values[index];
    }
}
```

and

```
 int responseCode = response.getInt(Consts.BILLING_RESPONSE_RESPONSE_CODE);
 boolean billingSupported = (responseCode == ResponseCode.RESULT_OK.ordinal());
```

to me it seems to be very odd to use an enum here. If the enum uses some different order it all fails and I thought an enum shouldn't rely on a certain ordinal value. Why is done this way and not just checked if the return code is zero?

Where in the documentation of Android is specified that for example a return code of 3 is RESULT_SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE. I only can guess this from the sample code.

Thanks, A.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual JSON `responseCode` is an int, so you need to convert it to an enum to use it in Java. They use an enum, to show that there is a finite set of response codes. Of course, it could have been a bunch of `final static int`'s, but that's less readable. The code you are quoting might have been written like this, which would probably better justify the use of enums:

```
 ResponseCode responseCode = ResponseCode.valueOf(response.getInt(Consts.BILLING_RESPONSE_RESPONSE_CODE));
 boolean billingSupported = (responseCode == ResponseCode.RESULT_OK);
```

As for the documentation, it's standard Java behaviour: enums start from 0 if you don't specify an explicit value. Cf.  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#ordinal%28%29

IAB billing response codes, etc are listed here: http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/billing_reference.html